# compile required after copying to new pc

Tags: ms-access

I've done a few updates to an access db and compiled it locally on my dev pc. All is working fine on my pc at the point

The accdb is then copied to the server and downloaded onto client pc's. Then when a user is using the DB (through a shortcut and with /runtime flag set) it will give an 'Access has encountered an error and has to close' type error and quit in one particular place.

If I open the accdb file normally and in the VBA IDE compile the application then it will work correctly.

Is this likely to be a reference issue? I've checked on a couple of machines and they have all the correct files, with the correct versions, in the right places?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try decompiling it then compile it.

Add /decompile to a shortcut for it. Run it then compact and repair. Then go to code and compile then compact and repair again.

Comment: I've finally had a chance to look at your suggestion and sadly it hasnt worked, any other ideas?

Comment: Did it definately decompile? You can tell because the code will let you compile it without any changes, whereas it's normally greyed out.